# Weird lambda behaviour in loops

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope, variable-assignment, lambda

I stumbled upon a behaviour in python that I have a hard time understanding.  This is the proof-of-concept code:

```
from functools import partial

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sequence = ['foo', 'bar', 'spam']
    loop_one = lambda seq: [lambda: el for el in seq]
    no_op = lambda x: x
    loop_two = lambda seq: [partial(no_op, el) for el in seq]
    for func in (loop_one, loop_two):
        print [f() for f in func(sequence)]
```

The output of the above is:

```
['spam', 'spam', 'spam']
['foo', 'bar', 'spam']
```

The behaviour of `loop_one` is surprising to me as I would expect it to behave as `loop_two`:`el` is an immutable value (a string) that changes at each loop, but **`lambda` seems to store a pointer to the "looping variable"**, like if the loop would recycle the same memory address for each element of the sequence.

The above behaviour is the same with full-blown functions with a for loop in them (so it is not a list-comprehension syntax).

**But wait: there is more... and more puzzling!**

The following script works like `loop_one`:

```
b = []
for foo in ("foo", "bar"):
    b.append(lambda: foo)

print [a() for a in b]
```

(output: `['bar', 'bar']`)

But watch what happens when one substitute the variable name `foo` with `a`:

```
b = []
for a in ("foo", "bar"):
    b.append(lambda: a)

print [a() for a in b]
```

(output: `[<function <lambda> at 0x25cce60>, <function <lambda> at 0x25cced8>]`)

Any idea of what is happening here? I suspect there must be some gotcha related to the underlying C implementation of my interpreter, but I haven't anything else (Jthon, PyPy or similar) to test if this behaviour is consistent across different implementations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `lambda: el` used in `loop_one` refers to a variable `el` which is not defined in the local scope. Therefore, Python looks for it next in the enclosing scope of the other `lambda`:

```
lambda seq: [lambda: el for el in seq]
```

in accordance with the so-called [LEGB rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules).

By the time `lambda: el` is called, this enclosing lambda has (of course) already been called and the list comprehension has been evaluated. The `el` used in the list comprehension is a local variable in this enclosing lambda. Its value is the one returned when Python looks for the value of `el` in `lambda: el`. That value for `el` is the **same** for all the different `lambda: el` functions in the list comprehension: it is the last value assigned to `el` in the `for el in seq` loop. Thus, `el` is always `'spam'`, the last value in `seq`.

---

You've already found one workaround, to use a closure such as your `loop_two`. Another way is to define `el` as a local variable with a default value:

```
loop_one = lambda seq: [lambda el=el: el for el in seq]
```

Answer (score 4):

The variables (`foo` in the following example) is binded not when the lambda is created, but when the lambda is called.

```
>>> b = []
>>> for foo in ("foo", "bar"):
...     b.append(lambda: foo)
...
>>> foo = "spam"
>>> print [a() for a in b]
['spam', 'spam']
```

---

```
>>> b = []
>>> for foo in ("foo", "bar"):
...     b.append(lambda foo=foo: foo)
...
>>> print [a() for a in b]
['foo', 'bar']
```